# cannot assign to array error for loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I want this code to filter out some different values and copy the results to a new spreadsheet saving it as the persons name (with date) and then send it as an attachment. I have two arrays, one containing names and the other containing e-mails.

However, I've run into some issues. I'm getting an error 'cannot assign to array' on the line of code: JCMails = Array("x@rvant.co.uk", "Y@rvant.co.uk").

```
Sub LOOKUP()   
  Dim myFilename As String
  Dim JCNames(2) As String
  Dim JCMails(2) As String
 JCNames = Array("x", "Y")
 JCMails = Array("X@rvnt.co.uk", "Y@rvnt.co.uk")
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Integer

j = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(JCNames)
myFilename = JCNames(i) & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")

Range("G1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A:N").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=JCNames(i)

With ActiveSheet
         lRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
         lCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRows, lCols)).Copy
End With
Workbooks.Add

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns.AutoFit

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = JCMails(i)
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "delays for" & JCNames
    .Body = "Hi there" & JCNames
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
Next i
end sub
```

please can someone tell me what am I doing wrong with my loop!? :(

Answer (score 2):

`Array` returns a variant containing an array.  You need to declare JCMails and JCNames simply as being of type Variant -- NOT as arrays.